# Get data from websocket and put it in state

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I want to get data from https://finnhub.io/docs/api/websocket-trades.

`console.log` is working, but I can't get it rendered to the screen.

Here are the code for example:

```
// function to get websocket's data

const streamingStockPrice = (symbol) => {
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws.finnhub.io?token=c7d2eiqad3idhma6grrg');

  // Connection opened -> Subscribe
  socket.addEventListener("open", function (event) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "subscribe", symbol }));
  });

  // Listen for messages
  const stockPrice = socket.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    const str = event.data;
    const currentStockPrice = str.substring(
      str.indexOf(`"p"`) + 4,
      str.indexOf(`,"s"`)
    );
    console.log(
      "Message from server ",
      str.substring(str.indexOf(`"p"`) + 4, str.indexOf(`,"s"`))
    );
    return currentStockPrice;
  });

  // Unsubscribe
  var unsubscribe = function (symbol) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: "unsubscribe", symbol: symbol }));
  };
  return stockPrice;
};

export default streamingStockPrice;
```

```
// render to screen
import streamingStockPrice from "./streamingStockPrice";

const toScreen = () => {
  const [stockPrice, setStockPrice] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setStockPrice(streamingStockPrice("GME"));
  }, [stockPrice]);
 return (
      <div>
            <h4>${stockPrice}</h4>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Please help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

First I want to warn you, this bit of code will create an infinite loop. What you are saying here is, if the stockPrice changes than set the stockPrice.

`const [stockPrice, setStockPrice] = useState(""); useEffect(() => { setStockPrice(streamingStockPrice("GME")); }, [stockPrice]);`

Now that's out of the way, since you are using react you should create a component for displaying the stockPrice and pass the setStockPrice to the component. Like shown below:

```
const streamStockPrice = (symbol, setStockPrice) => { setStockPrice(currentStockPrice) }
```

This way you set the stockprice in your main component and can use/show it there.